# What group should a munin-node run as on MacOSX?

Tags: mac-osx, munin

I'm installing a mac osx munin node, and the default value of

```
User root
Group root
```

Produces an error that there is no 'root' group. What should the group be for a munin node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to go with defaults, then group wheel or admin should work.

It may be better if you create a munin group to keep things clean.

HTH